# What does it mean to find the orbit IN a set?

Tags: group-theory

I am working on this assignment question (please do not give me the answer). But I am unsure of exactly what they are asking.

[image]

I understand the orbit as, informally, what an element $x$ can reach under the action of a group $G$. So if you asked me to find the orbit of an *element* of a set $X$, I can do that without issue. But what does it mean to find an orbit IN a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orbits of two elements of $S$ under the action of $G$ are either disjoint or equal, so $S$ can be partitioned into the orbits of its elements. Presumably the question is asking you to find this decomposition.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I could only guess that was the case but it is good to have verification.